# What are the Spectre and Meltdown issues related to FF52esr?

Tags: firefox, security

As far as I have read, including [USN-3516-1: Firefox vulnerabilities](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3516-1/), only FF57 (in 57.0.4) is being updated due to these issues.

As some people are using FF52esr (currently 52.5.3), is there any downside or different plan for these users? I haven't seen any updates for these issues.

Answer (score 1):

[`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) is [disabled by default on Firefox 52 ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2018-01/).

Firefox ESR 52.6.0 has been released. From [blog post on Mozilla](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/01/03/mitigations-landing-new-class-timing-attack/):

> `performance.now()` mitigations will be included in the regularly scheduled Firefox 52.6 ESR release on January 23, 2018.

Also see [mfsa2018-03 security advisory](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2018-03/).